# Can't see video player controls using `libvlcsharp`

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, libvlcsharp

I'm using `libvlcsharp` to play video, in iOS controls are showing but in android there are white boxes instead of controls. Kindly help

Here is XAML

```
<vlc:MediaPlayerElement x:Name="myvideo" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="200"/>
```

Code Behind

```
 LibVLC _libVLC;
        public TestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Core.Initialize();
            _libVLC = new LibVLC();
            var media = new Media(_libVLC, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", FromType.FromLocation);
            myvideo.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media) { EnableHardwareDecoding = true};
            myvideo.MediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

[image: See here]

Comment: you're missing the fonts. please share full code

Comment: @mfkl i've updated my question pls see. Also i'm already using `FontAwesomeIcons` in my project. Icons are displaying in my components but not here.

Comment: that's not full code.. put it in a github repo